# extract value from dictionary in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with one of column:

```
 data['countries']

"[{'iso_3166_1': 'KR', 'name': 'South Korea'}]"
"[{'iso_3166_1': 'US', 'name': 'United States of America'}]"
```

How can extract ONLY country names: `'South Korea','United States of America'` etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
import json
import numpy as np

countries = [ json.loads(c.replace("'", '"')) for c in data['countries'] if not np.isnan(c)]
country_names = [cn for cn[0]['name'] in countries]
```

And the output will be:

```
>>> ['South Korea', 'United States of America']
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: @Ray you probably have missing values, skip them first.

Comment: @Ray Updated my answer to exclude any `NaN` entries in your dataframe. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your DataFrame but just parse the content of the string it contains, you could use split.

```
>>> a = "[{'iso_3166_1': 'KR', 'name': 'South Korea'}]"
>>> a.split("'name': ")[1].split("'")[1]
'South Korea'
```

or:

```
def f(a):
    return a.split("'name': ")[1].split("'")[1]

countries = [f(a) for a in data['countries']]
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: This error doesn't make sense. You show strings in you data column, double check your DataFrame.

Comment: Try `data.loc[data['countries'].notna(), 'countries'].str.split("'name': ").str[1].str.split("'").str[1]`

Comment: @alec_djinn it's almost certainly because pandas uses `np.NaN` (which is a float) for missing values.

Comment: @Dan that could be. The OP should drop the nan values.

Comment: data.loc[data['countries'].notna(), 'countries'].str.split("'name': ").str[1].str.split("'").str[1] works now. Thanks Dan

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
data['countries'] = data['countries'].apply(lambda x: eval(x))
data['countries'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['name'])
```

**Output**

```
0                 South Korea
1    United States of America
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

---

```
list(data[1].apply(lambda x: x[0]['name']))
```

**Output**

```
['South Korea', 'United States of America']
```

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: whats type(data['countries'][0]) .. ? convert them to list try the update